# Apache2 Virtual Host is ignored except for ServerAlias

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm attempting to have domainname.com and [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) go to my virtual host instead of the 000-default host. While going to [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) works as intended and returns the virtual host site, domainname.com still returns the apache2 "It works!" page.

(Actual domain name was replaced with domainname.com)

Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DirectoryIndex index.html
<Directory /var/www/domainname.com>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears my browser had cached the result of domainname.com and continued to serve the cached copy. Other browsers display the correct result.

This seriously had me stumped for over an hour and clearing my cache was the fix.